# Rails 4 / Ruby 2 how to put the label in the input

Tags: ruby, forms, input, ruby-on-rails-4, label

In rails 4 and ruby 2, with the idea to have more room for a form, what is the way to put the title of the label in the input?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean placeholder? I mean to say fill the field with a default value, when the input box is displayed. In that case, just add `:placeholder => "label"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Kirti said you can use a placeholder, but if you really want a label you can use [label_tag or label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "label_tag", this would be what you want:

```
label_tag 'name', 'Your name'
# will output => <label for="name">Your name</label>
```

[label_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag)